# How to use JSP page templates in my custom tag library

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jsp-tags

I have custom tag library project (using `maven`) and have user project that uses my custom tag library. I want to add jsp template to custom tag library project so that jsp tags would be generated according to this template when used in user project. I've tried to locate the jsp template at `resources/META-INF` and `resources/WEB-INF` folders of custom tag project and HTTP-request it from custom tag class, but this is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locating JSPs in the folder `resources/META-INF` was correct. It have not worked on my case just because of old version of WAR-file with no JSP in it which maven couldn't delete because of the process that held my war-file.